# android EditText disable spell check and leave multiline

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText which is intended to be multiline. 
A default input type performs spell checking and red lines are drawn below the EditText if a word is "incorrect". 
I want to disable this feature.
I tried `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`, but then EditText is no longer multiline.
Please tell me what are possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: shame on me; don't tell anyone that I've asked this question =) +1

Comment: Happens... You just needed some coffee.. ;)